# subprocess.call() to remove except *.txt files

Tags: python-3.x

i have this shell command:

```
rm !(*.esLA.ass|*.mp4|*.txt|*.sh|*.py)
```

i was trying with:

```
files = [i for i in glob.glob("*") if i not in ('*.esLA', '*.mp4')]
subprocess.call(['rm','-r'] + files)
```

but it deletes me EVERYTHING

can you help me please???

Comment: In the "not in" condition we don't use globbing, but literal strings.

Comment: any idea on how to add *.mp4??? for example??

Answer (score 0):

You're not using glob with the file names, '*' is interpreted as a string literal in this case so you're just deleting all in glob('*'). Use just the extension like:

```
[fileName for fileName in glob('*') if fileName.split('.')[-1] not in ['.esLA', '.mp4']]
```

Comment: Well then add .ass as a file extension to exclude with .mpa and .esLA